# cluster number by range in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data look like the following:

```
Mike   5
Mike   100
Mike   101
Mike   106
Mike   95
Mike   1000
Mike   1001
Mike   1010
Jen    2006
Jen    2001
Jen    2010
Jen    3000
Jen    10
```

I want to cluster the numbers by absolute value of `20`, and leave the smallest one in each cluster.

The result looks like this:

```
Mike   5
Mike   95
Mike   1000
Jen    2006
Jen    3000
Jen    10
```

Is there any way to do this?
I have thought about `GROUP BY` with intervals,
but it does not make sense if the cluster cross the intervals,
for an example, if I set the ranges are
`1-20, 21-40, 41-60`
but if my data have:

```
Mike   35
Mike   39
Mike   41
Mike   45
```

it will be split into two clusters

```
Mike   35
Mike   41
```

what I want:

```
Mike   35
```

Thanks!

Comment: You must formulate a precise and unambiguous criterion for dividing into clusters. So that anyone who takes the criterion description and the data set always gets the same result. now your criteria is too approximate... for example, in corrent state the data array (10, 25, 40) can be divided as both (10, 25) + (40) and (10) + (25, 40).

Comment: "I want to cluster the numbers by absolute value of 20".  This doesn't make sense to me.  More explanation would help.

Comment: @mike . . . If I understand correctly, then 2001 should be a cluster for Jen, not 2006.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the "smallest" value for each name to start a "cluster".  That cluster in turn contains all rows for the same name within a value of 20.  This is then repeated for the remaining clusters.

This suggests a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive tn as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by val) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select name, val, seqnum, val as cluster_val, 1 as cluster_num
      from tn
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select cte.name, tn.val, tn.seqnum,
             (case when tn.val < cte.cluster_val + 20 then cte.cluster_val else tn.val end) as cluster_val,
             (case when tn.val < cte.cluster_val + 20 then cte.cluster_num + 1 else 1 end) as cluster_num
      from cte join
           tn
           on tn.name = cte.name and tn.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte
where cluster_num = 1
order by name, val;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8733794c6a695c5b8883872fae426d9b) is a db<>fiddle.